# Segmentation faults running in rufus-scheduler

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have an application that uses rufus-scheduler to run a variety of background tasks.  After recently upgrading to Ruby 1.9.2, we continue to have intermittent segmentation errors and/or bus errors.  The error will occur in different libraries.

The one thing that I've identified is that the same functions that will cause a segmentation fault when running under rufus-scheduler will NOT fail when run from a console.

This occurs on two platforms (OSX for development, ubuntu for production) in the same way.

Does anyone have any ideas on what differs in the runtime between the rufus-scheduler environment and running something straight from "rails c" console?

Thanks in advance...

Russell

Answer (score 0):

You seem to imply it worked with Ruby 1.8.x. What Ruby 1.9.2 patchlevel anyway ?

Rufus-scheduler is a very dumb library, you could replace it altogether with things like

```
Thread.new do
  loop do
    sleep 60 * 60
    trigger_my_hourly_task
  end
end
Thread.new do
  loop do
    sleep 24 * 60 * 60
    trigger_my_daily_task
  end
end
```

and see if the problem still occurs.

There is no rufus-scheduler environment, rufus-scheduler is pure-ruby, it lives in the environment of your server and your rails application. Running things in the "rails c" console is running stuff in a brand new process, with no accumulated memory usage, it's "blue sky".

If you really think it's a rufus-scheduler issue, you should be able to come up with a detailed way of reproducing the issue.